# how to make API15 work with processing GUI?

Tags: android, processing

I am trying to develop an android app using processing. The app is very simple for now - it just draws a line on the screen.

I have downloaded several versions of the android sdk libraries (4.0.3(API15), 2.3.3(API10), etc). However, I find that the app only works on a 2.3 phone, it does not work on a 4.0.4 phone. The message is: "waiting for the device to become available"

Apparently, although both libraries are available, only one of them is getting selected. I also tried completely deleting the API10, so that only API15 is installed. But then I get the same error. I read somewhere (maybe in the book "rapid android development") that API10 has to be present for processing to work.

So then, what is the solution for using API15 with the processing platform?

The android manifest shows this code (I have added the item for targetSdkVersion myself):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="processing.test.lolsweg">
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
   <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
   <application android:debuggable="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="LolSweg">
      <activity android:name=".LolSweg">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
      </activity>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

Since the android sdk manager handles the libraries internally (the gui shows all the libraries available), how do I tell the gui (or fix the manisfest) so that the right API gets selected?

I have seen similar questions (eg [16613444](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613444)), but their solutions refer to the eclipse platform, not to the processing platform. I am using win7.

Answer (score 0):

While trying out an app for eclipse, I accidentally found the solution for this problem.

For an android device to work, the necessary ADB interface is required. This is usually 
installed when you connect the device with a usb to the computer, but in some cases this
is not installed by default. In my case, the Nexus 4 was having problems - the ADB interface was not
installed. This can be downloaded separately from the internet [nexus4](http://download.clockworkmod.com/test/UniversalAdbDriverSetup6.msi) and [lg-g2](http://www.lg.com/in/support-mobile/lg-G2-D802-32GB). After they are installed, you can 
click on "Run on Device", it should work.